# C# XNA Making a texture appear in a new window?

Tags: c#, xna, window

I'm playing around with random map generation and what I want to do is:

- Input a command to generate a random map
- A texture will be created resembling the generation, each pixel resembling each tile
- Then a new window will pop-up, without removing the other one that will contain the texture

So I know how to do this except the last part. So would someone please tell me how to create a new window and draw a texture to this window? Thank you.

Comment: While this is a good question, I suggest posting it on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com for a more appropriate audience.

Comment: Do you need 2 forms or would drawing to a RenderTarget2D and saving the results of the call as a Texture2D suffice?